# How do I fix this function so that I can input a List of any class

Tags: c#, collections, generic-collections

How do I fix this function so that I can input a List of any class

```
private static List<Type> CopyObjList(List<Type> Group, List<Type> AddGroup)
{
    foreach (Type obj in AddGroup)
        Group.Add(obj);
    return Group;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics and AddRange

```
private static void CopyObjList<T>(List<T> Group, List<T> AddGroup)
{
      Group.AddRange(AddGroup);
}
```

Return type is not mendatory since List is a reference type.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you just need to add a range of elements to an existing List.
You do not need to write the function for this. You can simply use

```
AddRange
```

Method of the List class

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to think of:

- Generics
- Do we want to be able to add derived types too
- Do you really want to modify the existing list.

  ```
  private static List<TList> CopyObjList<TList, TElem>(List<TList> Group, List<TElem> AddGroup)
    where TElem : TList
  {
    List<TList> result = new List<TList>(Group);

    foreach (var item in AddGroup)
    {
      result.Add(item);
    }

    return result;
  }
  ```

This will leave the original list unchanged, return the new list, and also allow instances of derived classes to be added as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
private static List<T> CopyObjList<T>(List<T> Group, List<T> AddGroup)
{
    foreach(T obj in AddGroup)
        Group.Add(obj);
    return Group;
}
```

This allows you to pass a compile time type into the function.

Example:

```
List<string> employees = new List<string> { "Bob", "Joe", "Fred" };
List<string> newHires = new List<string> { "Steve", "John" };

List<string> allEmployees = CopyObjList<string>(employees, newHires);

foreach(string employeeName in allEmployees)
    Console.WriteLine(employeeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question, but it seems like you need a collection that accepts any type. If so, an ArrayList can do the job:

```
private static ArrayList CopyObjList(ArrayList Group, ArrayList AddGroup) 
{ 
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(Group);
    arr.AddRange(AddGroup);
    return arr;
}
```

If the group to add may be different from ArrayList, then you can have ICollection for it:

```
private static ArrayList CopyObjList(ArrayList Group, ICollection AddGroup)
{
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(Group);
    arr.AddRange(AddGroup);
    return arr;
}
```